# Remote register of ocx using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to register an OCX file on a remote machine using Powershell 2.0.

This doesn't doesn't work:

```
$LocalOCXPath = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxapi.ocx"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock { "C:\windows\system32\Regsvr32.exe $args" } -argumentlist $LocalOCXPath
```

But this does:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock { & 'regsvr32.exe' 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxapi.ocx' }
```

I really need to be able to pass the path in via a variable, but I don't think I can do that using option 2.  And I have no idea why option 1 doesn't work.  By doesn't work, I mean that powershell looks like it invokes the command properly, but when I look on the remote machine, the ocx file isn't registered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overenginnering, try:

```
$LocalOCXPath = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxapi.ocx"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock { & 'regsvr32.exe' $LocalOCXPath }
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Command runs the scriptblock in the context of the remote system so your $LocalOCXPath variable doesn't exist there.  In PowerShell 3.0 you can force the variable to be seen in the remote context by prefixing it with $Using:, as in $Using:$LocalOCXPath.